# How to create a badge component for custom components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am facing a really nasty issue, I need to create a badge component that it'll be places over a custom component.

This is my first attempt to create something similar in React, with HTML is way easier because you work directly with the DOM.

In this case instead I need to create a badge that will highlight a new component/feature, when you click on it a popup get's open with a bit of text that'll explains what the component is about, aka it's functionality. Telling you this because I need to listen for `onClick` and it's not possible to use pseudo-elements.

## The base idea

```
<BadgeComponent position="top left">
    <CustomComponent />
</BadgeComponent>
```

Since I can't use a pseudo-element that'll inherit all the element CSS properties this is my thinking:

- do not change the `CustomComponent` because each time could be different
- the `BadgeComponent` is a wrapper that creates a `div` with `position:relative` (so I can position the badge wherever I want)
- `BadgeComponent` needs to be `display: inline-block` otherwise it'll change the overall layout
- I need to take the `CustomComponent` box-model properties, remove from it and apply them to the `BadgeComponent`. This mostly because `margin`s are messing with the `BadgeComponent` size and position the badge itself will be trickyer

Basically I need to take the CSS properties of the DOM element rendered from the child component.

## The approach

So I've [been experimenting with some code](https://codesandbox.io/s/badge-notification-component-gfbb4) before came here and my first attempt has been to dinamically pass a `ref` to the child component of `BadgeComponent` with this snippet:

```
{React.Children.map(this.props.children, (element, idx) => {
    if (idx > 0) return; // don't care if it has more childrens, at least for now.
    return React.cloneElement(element, { ref: this.newFeature });
})}
```

I also thought to take the `CustomComponent` as a prop of `BadgeComponent`, like so:

```
<BadgeComponent position="top left" target={ CustomComponent }>
```

But I didn't (yet) followed this path because I thought that at the end of the day `this.props.target` it's basically the same of `this.props.children` and didn't earn anything doing so. Am I right?

I know that in React we have `ref` to get a reference to the DOM created from a component but in this case is not applicable because I am not applying the `ref` to the component that renders an HTML, I am applying it to `CustomComponent` that gets cloned and it doesn't pass to the DOM.

From my experiment everything works fine if I pass an HTML element, in the [experimental code](https://codesandbox.io/s/badge-notification-component-gfbb4) I have a `div.box` that gets the badge in the position that I want but as soon as I pass the `Button` I got the following error: `Window.getComputedStyle: Argument 1 does not implement interface Element.`

I am using `window.getComputedStyle` to get the CSS properties I care about.

## My research

I've been looking all around the web and I've seen a [nice implementation](https://swizec.com/blog/getting-the-css-out-of-rendered-react-components/swizec/9108) that, unfortunately, just works with styled components or styled defined inline in `<style>`. I am looking to not use NPM packages as [this one](https://github.com/signavio/react-stick) because firstly I believe that it is possible to implement without reach for an additional package and second actually I do not like much the way that the sticky/badge get's implemented (with all respect obviously).

I don't know where to look anymore, I am not an expert JS/React developer (been WP theme developer for 10 years) so probably there is some basic concept that I missunderstand?

I've read about `findDOMNode` (looks will be deprecated soon) and `forwardRef` in the React ecosystem but I do not think that's the way to go, am I wrong?

I do not want the copy/paste code, well if you're so gentle to fork the codesandbox and share the solution will be great but I am trying to learn here: there is a way to get a reference of the rendered HTML element from any component?

Thinking that this is the missing part, if I can reach the DOM my code is already working

Comment: if you absolutely position the badge component why would margins effect it?

Comment: Yes, if you try the shared codesandox you'll see that margins of child increases the size of the paren, at least the top/bottom ones are affecting the height. Haven't tryed the horizontal ones yet.

Comment: not sure im following. the `.box` is the exact width / height from what its class style defines (300px X 300px) What do you want it to look like?

Comment: Oh wait you're saying the styling on the sticky component shouldn't account for the child margin? meaning whatever height / width the child is, the parent should be regardless of the childs margins? Why dont you just use css to remove the margin off the child [**like this**](https://codesandbox.io/s/badge-notification-component-qvq4k)?

Comment: I just [**added a few default values**](https://codesandbox.io/s/badge-notification-component-qvq4k?file=/src/components/Sticky/Sticky.scss) to show how you can position still with just css. you could make this work with numerical values from props if you want as well.

Comment: Thank you so much @JohnRuddell for your interest but I need to take the margins of child and apply them to parent because if not the resulting component will have a wrong position. BTW good idea to use `*` for childs and `translate` to position the badge, I was too into JS land 

Maybe I need to improve the codebase to create a better starting point but basically, you can see an example [here](https://i.ibb.co/7YsnXRc/badge-example.jpg).

If I remove margins (and margins are just for now) from child and don't apply them to parent the button will loose spacing.

Comment: yea part of the issue is your components are defining margins and stuff. I usually avoid that so its easier to compose elements together. If I want specific spacing / layouts then i usually let a parent dictate that. So few thoughts... you can totally still use the DOM here. on mount you can grab the element by an ID or something and do what you need to. If theres a much simpler way to do something with the DOM I usually opt for that route. But I do think you're too much in the JS land as well regarding styling here. I would look for a better way to render / make them more composable

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts I really appreciate them. The thing is that I the project I am working on it's in the growing phase and refactor all the components is gonna be heavy. I've started to wander if I could get away with an utility function... Something that, if applied to the component it'll get all its styles and store them in Redux. Going to try something out, if you think it'll be just a waste of time just write STOP 